# Is there any way django- rest-framework-filters (query) working using django-html "search" button for the first page of server?

Tags: django, html, django-templates, django-rest-framework

in django filters we can get data easily like
for example :  http:127.../api/?first_name=kiran
(gives output for first_name is kiran )

or
http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/?last_name=Prajapti

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework import filters
from WBCIS.serializers import WbcisSerializer
from WBCIS.models import Wbcis 


from rest_framework import generics
import django_filters.rest_framework

class WbcisViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Wbcis.objects.all()
    model=Wbcis
    serializer_class = WbcisSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)

    filter_fields = ('first_name','last_name',)
```

So, when we run the server 
http:/api/?first_name=Kiran&last_name=Prajapati
query works and gives exact output :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58747e0b1a39f11292539da0"),
    "first_name" : "kiran",
    "last_name" : "prajapati",
}
```

So, Now, I want to write same query but using django-html button [first_name] [last_name]  [ search]

So,ones we fill the first_name and last_name that will run the query and gives me exact output :

for example : when we run server
http:127.0.0.1:8000/

html page showing

[first_name]     [ last_name]            [search button]

then we can here put the input,
first_name=Kiran,         last_name = Prajapati    [search]

then it will show our data in json format,
same query  http:.//api/?first_name=Kiran&last_name=Prajapati

output :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58747e0b1a39f11292539da0"),
    "first_name" : "kiran",
    "last_name" : "prajapati",
}
```

Can you tell me how to get data in json format when we use django-html button  instead of typing  http:127./api/?first_name=kiran&last_name=Prajapati ?

Answer (score 2):

1st take data by the hep of post method.
url is like

```
url('^search/(?P<firstname>.+)/$', Search.as_view({'post': 'search'}), name='search')
```

serializer class

```
class SearchSerializer(self, request, *args):
    class Meta:
       model = ModelName
       fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
       read_only = ('id',)
```

and queryset is

```
obj = ModelName.__Meta.filter(first_name__startwith=request.data['firstname'])
return obj
```

in view

```
class SearchViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def search(self, request):
       obj = ModelName.objects.filter(first_name__startwith=request.data['firstname'])
       serializer = SearchSerializer(obj, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

Comment: ,there need to create html file with search button ,right ? how query will works then ?

Comment: where the search button add url

Comment: oh so no need to create html ?

Comment: Aryan,  this need ? and queryset is

obj = ModelName.__Meta.filter(first_name__startwith=request.firstname)
return obj

Comment: give me error : SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use APIView or APIViewset instead of ModelViewset. Here is an example using APIView:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response

class WbcisViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Wbcis.objects.filter(first_name=request.GET.get('firstname'))
        data = serializers.serialize('json', list(querySet), fields=('firstname','id'))
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: so we can get in the first page "serach button" for first_name : ?  so, if I type : kiran , it will gives data in json format?

Comment: you will have to hit this api when you click on search button using form submit in your html. It will give json output.

Comment: but how to create first page html where we can type first_name and this query will run ?